# Mantle and CoreData integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to use Mantle for all of my Models in an iOS app (just to provide JSON serialization by default) and I'm trying to use these models with core data too (It should be posible as I've read).

I've foudn the way to insert with ManagedObjectContext....

```
[MTLManagedObjectAdapter managedObjectFromModel:plan insertingIntoContext:self.managedObjectContext error:nil];
```

But how can I fetch results back?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Fetch**

Grab your object from CoreData with an `NSFetchRequest` as normal (if you don't know how to do that then I suggest learning CoreData properly first).

**2. Convert**

Then:

```
NSError *error;
SomeModel *mantleModelObject = [MTLManagedObjectAdapter modelOfClass:[SomeModel class] fromManagedObject:managedObject error:&error];
```

At the time of writing the Mantle docs are pretty lacking, I've had to browse the source code to learn the workings of the library.